# How to rewrite URL using htaccess for clean url (remove unnecessary parameter from url)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I am working on localhost for PHP project. I need some solution.

Current URL : `http://localhost/project/portfolio/php_files/port_sub_sidebar.php?x=opencart`

Now, i want to show in URL like this:  `http://localhost/project/portfolio/opencart`

How's that possible doing change in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.css|\.js)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

you can get the url by the code below

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$segments = explode("/",$url);
print_r($segments);
```

then  you can implement your routing system based on the provided segments